# const char (&)[N] vs const char * for string literal

Tags: c++

`foo(const char *)` is chosen over template version for `"hello"`. How to make the compiler choose template version instead?

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
void foo(const char (&)[N])
{
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
}

void foo(const char *)
{
    std::cout << "char*" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo("hello");
    char a[] = "world";
    foo(a);
}
```

Comment: Try `foo<sizeof(a)>(a);`

Comment: `foo<>("hello")` can force the template version.